# How we can identify which version of Grafana getting installed using Grafana operator

Tags: openshift, grafana

I am trying to install Grafana in openshift cluster using Grafana operator. Before installing it, Just wanted to know which version of Grafana will get installed using the Grafana operator.

Grafana operator, I am trying to install is 4.8.0 in OpenShift cluster 4.8. Just curious how we can get it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find the version of grafana on the repository, here.

It looks like `7.5.17` version of Grafana is default image.

https://github.com/grafana-operator/grafana-operator/blob/v4.8.0/controllers/constants/constants.go

According the document, You can overwrite it with an argument.

https://github.com/grafana-operator/grafana-operator/blob/master/documentation/deploy_grafana.md#operator-flags